# Is there an advantage to using properties for objects I reference from classes that inherit

Tags: c#

Here's the code I have:

```
public class BaseButtonSheet : PopupBase
{
    public BaseButtonSheet()
    {
        BindingContext = new BaseButtonSheetViewModel();
        contentStack.Children.Add(new PopupHeaderLabel("Screen Options"));
        grid.Children.Add(new BaseButton("Add Deck", "AddCmd"), 0, 0);
        contentStack.Children.Add(grid);
    }
}

public class PopupBase : Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages.PopupPage
{
    public StackLayout contentStack;
    public Grid grid;

    public PopupBase()
    {
```

What I am unsure of is if it's more common and if there is an advantage to create contentStack and grid as properties because I will be accessing them from a different class.

Comment: The rule of thumb says that public fields are bad (unless they are constants or static readonly fields) and anything that is public should be encapsulated in a property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As well as the advice from Microsoft, there are advantages to wrapping access to variable in properties.

You can change the way a property is implemented in an inheriting class.

e.g.  You could have an AdvancedButtonSheet, and redefine how the contentStack property is retrieved, providing additional benefit for your advanced buttons, just by calling the "same" property.

Answer (score 4):

Because they are public I would use properties.

See this:

> Generally, you should use fields only for variables that have private or protected accessibility. Data that your class exposes to client code should be provided through methods, properties, and indexers

[C# programming guide, Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields)